# Decode Base64 string to byte array

Tags: python, string, embedded, base64, decode

I would create a python script that decode a Base64 string to an array of byte (or array of Hex values).

The embedded side of my project is a micro controller that creates a base64 string starting from raw byte. The string contains some no-printable characters (for this reason I choose base64 encoding).

On the Pc side I need to decode the the base64 string and recover the original raw bytes.

My script uses python 2.7 and the base64 library:

```
base64Packet = raw_input('Base64 stream:')

packet = base64.b64decode(base64Packet )

sys.stdout.write("Decoded packet: %s"%packet)
```

The resulting string is a characters string that contains some not printable char.

Is there a way to decode base64 string to byte (or hex) values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already *have* that bytestring. What output were you expecting and what do you see? Perhaps you wanted to use `%r` instead when printing?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: After decoding I would have a python list that contain each single byte.

Comment: Why do you need that? Do you need to manipulate the bytes? A `str` object is already a sequence, you can address each byte with `packet[index]`, for example, or loop over the string with `for byte in packet:`.

Comment: You can create the list by just using `list(packet)`, producing a list of 1-character (byte) strings. Or perhaps you want to use a `bytearray` object instead, but it isn't clear what you want to do with your data. You haven't given us your use case.

Comment: Yes I need to manipulate specific bytes! For example I want to parse the byte. Can I convert string to list to manipulate the bytes? Thanks

Comment: Parsing doesn't require any conversion; just use indexing or slicing. The `struct` module for example doesn't need anything else but the string you already have.

Comment: Yes I know,  but I prefer to have a list with integer or hex value to debug the script.

Comment: Then you want a `bytearray()` instance; just use `bytearray(packet)`. A bytearray is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0-255, one integer per byte.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I solved with this code line: packetString = list(bytearray(base64.b64decode(base64Packet))). Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) for exactly this. Possibly the [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) module and [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) can be helpful, too.

```
import binascii
import struct

binstr=b"thisisunreadablebytes"

encoded=binascii.b2a_base64(binstr)
print encoded
print binascii.a2b_base64(encoded)

ba=bytearray(binstr)
print list(ba)

print binascii.b2a_hex(binstr)
print struct.unpack("21B",binstr)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide an example for the use of bytearray, binascii and struct to solve my problem? I'm not a master of python!

Comment: added examples - if you can be more specific on what input should become waht i can extend...

Comment: Thanks for your example! I obtain the list of integer values with this code line: stapacketString = list(bytearray(base64.b64decode(base64Packet))). Is this the correct way? For my scope this works.

Comment: Looks correct - actually `bytearray`s behave like `list`s (except for printing) so constructing a `list` is only needed for prettier printing. Glad I could help :)