# How to correctly encode a string for unzipping with zlib in Python

Tags: python, zlib

I am writing a Python function that receives a string and decompresses the string using [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html).

I am trying to translate from the following Go code to Python, that I know works (please excuse the one letter variable names, this code was written by someone else):

```golang
var b bytes.Buffer
r := bytes.NewReader(s) // s is a []byte
z, err := zlib.NewReader(r)
if err != nil {
    // Error handling
}
_, err = io.Copy(&b, z)
if err != nil {
    // Error handling
}
err = z.Close()
if err != nil {
    // Error handling
}
```

The data is always received in Python as a string type rather than a `bytes` or byte array type - this is outside my control. (For more context, see below.)

How can I properly encode or convert the string to a `bytes` object that will be accepted by [`zlib.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress)?

Do I need to set the `wbits` parameter to something in particular?

Here is what I tried so far:

```py
uncompressed = zlib.decompress(s.encode())
```

I am getting this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

I also tried

```py
uncompressed = zlib.decompress(bytearray(s, 'utf-8'))
```

and

```py
uncompressed = zlib.decompress(bytes(s, 'utf-8'))
```

but both failed with the same error.

#### Additional context

For those who are interested, here is some further context.

The system I am working on serializes a Go struct and sends the data as a raw array of bytes over the network. To save bandwidth, a portion of the data is compressed before serializing to bytes.

The reason the Go code always gets the data as a `[]byte` is because it can unmarshal the JSON raw bytes with `json.Unmarshal`, like this:

```golang
env := RedactedStructName{}
err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &env) // buf is a []byte
```

I did not include this code above because I wanted to keep my question as simple as possible. In Python, the `RedactedStructName` struct does not exist.

On the other end, the Python program that I am working on needs to deserialize the data and decompress the compressed data so that it can work on it.

The data, when passed through `json.loads`, produces a Python dictionary. The compressed payload is a value in the dictionary. I don't know why, but `json.loads` always causes the compressed data to be a Python string rather than a Python `bytes` or bytearray object.

Comment: *"The data is always received as a string type"* - That just seems wrong. I suggest you out ask whoever *does* have control over that to fix it. Or at least to tell you how they created the string from bytes.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I updated the comment to be correct on the type of `s` in the Go code I am translating to Python. I also added a new section at the bottom of my question with additional context to explain why the data I receive is always a string type.

Comment: Ah, JSON. Whose strings are sequences of Unicode characters, which in Python is `str`. But the original compression surely produced *bytes*, which then *somehow* got converted to the Unicode strings in JSON. The question is how. We could guess, but I wouldn't. Ought to be documented somewhere or at least be visible in the code that does it. Maybe to Go people it's clear from the `json.Unmarshal` snippet, but I'm not one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

As pointed out by Kelly Bundy in their comment, JSON strings are sequences of Unicode characters, which in Python is `str`. To my knowledge, in Go, `json.Unmarshal`, when passed an object as the second argument, would automatically handle the conversion.

In the case of Python, I needed to convert from the `str` to `bytes` like this, using the [built-in `binascii` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

```py
import binascii
uncompressed = zlib.decompress(binascii.a2b_base64(s))
```

I found this solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39210134/8593689).

Comment: So Base64 was the missing link/information. How did you figure that out now?

Comment: To be honest, it was a guess. But I did verify that the data output by this Python code matched the data output by the Go code I was translating to Python. If I have time, I might look closer at the other team's Go code to try to puzzle out where the data is base64-encoded just to be extra certain my Python code is correct. Thanks for your help, your comments helped guide my thinking.